# Is it possible to compile a Xamarin project against .NET Framework instead of .NET Standard?

Tags: .net, xamarin, .net-standard

There are some dependencies of my app that are not available in .NET Standard; I was wondering if it was possible to compile against .NET Framework instead. I kinda doubt it but it wouldn't hurt to ask! :)

Comment: You can use the .NET API Browser to determine what Xamarin.iOS|Android supports: i.e.
   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web?view=xamarinandroid-7.1 So if you are trying to include the full System.Web into a Xamarin.iOS|Android project, it will not work...

Comment: Nope. An API on .NET Framework is usually Windows only. Unless it is part of .NET Standard which can be implemented on other platforms, no Xamarin applications can consume it. That's exactly why most Xamarin projects target .NET Standard 2.0 (2.1 in the future).

Answer (score -1):

Yes! It's a common issue and there's a lot of ways around it!

1. One way that's not recommended, is to clone a blank Shared Library Project and use that, so you won't face that issue at all.
2. The second way is to go to Core Project Options in Visual Studio, choose .NET Portable, and select your Target Framework, as shown in the picture [image: Core Project Options in Visual Studio]
3. The third way is to allow your project to use .Net standard, but allow some dependencies/packages that target the .Net framework instead

Let me know if that answers your question